# Efficient pandas operation for columnwise functions on two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two numerical dataframes (df1 and df2), each with a common index but with different column headers. I want to apply a function that takes: for the ith column of df1, and the jth column of df2, apply the Pearson correlation function (or cosine similarity, or similar user defined function), and return the number.

I want to return the number into a dataframe, df3, where the columns of df1 are the index of df3, the columns of df2 are the columns of df3, and the cells represent the value of the correlation between the two vectors (columns) from df1 and df2.

*not all of the values are populated. Where there's a difference, match only on the inner join of the two vectors (this can be done in the user defined function). Assume df1 and df2 have a different length/number of columns to each other.

Example: I have a dataframe (df1) of male dating profiles, where the columns are the names of the men, and the row index is their interest in a certain topic, between 0 and 100.

I have a second dataframe (df2) of female dating profiles in the same way.

I want to return a matrix of Males along the side, Females across the top, and the number corresponds to the similarity coefficient between the two profiles, for each man/woman pair.

eg:
df1

```
          bob  joe  carlos 
 movies   50   45   90
 sports   10   NaN  10
 walking  20   NaN  50
 skiing   NaN  80   40
```

df2

```
          mary anne sally 
 movies   40   70   NaN
 sports   50   0    30
 walking  80   10   50
 skiing   30   NaN  40
```

Desired output, df3:

```
          mary anne sally 
 bob      4.53 19.3 77.4
 joe      81.8 75.7 91.0
 carlos   45.8 12.2 18.8
```

I tried this with the classic double for loop, but even I know this is the work of satan in Pandas world. The tables are relatively large, so reasonable efficiency is important (which the below obviously isn't). Thanks in advance.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.columns, columns=df2.columns)

for usera in df1:
    for userb in df2:
        df3.loc[userb, usera] = myfunc(df1[usera], df2[userb])
```

Comment: Perhaps the built-in [corrwith() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) could help?

Comment: I love this community + the helpful people at pandas. Thanks @G.Anderson, let me try that and see how I get on. It looks like it will suit my needs

Comment: I always say: if you want to do anything in pandas, there's almost always a built-in function and it's always better than what I come up with lol

Comment: For some reason `corrwith` only gives me a series of `NaN`.

Comment: yeah I can't quite make it work for me either, axis = 0 gives an empty series, axis = 1 gives a single series of NaN (though I think it should be axis = 0)

Comment: @BenJones Are you looking for: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).corr().loc[df1.columns, df2.columns]`

Comment: According to the doc, `corrwith()` first aligns the rows / columns and calculate correlations on corresponding rows / columns of df1 and df2. This question requires to return a matrix for each column pairs in df1 and df2 so `corrwith()` does not work.

Comment: Not sure how to improve your nested loops but using `.at` instead of `.loc` is much faster cell assignment in `pandas`

Comment: Can you modify your function to take a single column from the first dataframe, and the whole 2nd dataframe as arguments, then perform vectorized calculations in that, and returning an array? If so, you can do a single `for` loop over just the first dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented with a few alternatives of your code and this one is the fastest as of now:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(([myfunc_np(col_a, col_b) for col_b in df2.values.T] for col_a in df1.values.T), 
                    index=df1.columns, columns=df2.columns)
```

Here `myfunc_np` is a numpy version of `myfunc` that acts on numpy arrays directly rather than pandas series.

Further performance improvement would likely require to vectorize `myfunc_np`, i.e. having a `myfunc_np_vec` that takes one column `u1` in `df1` and the entire `df2`, and returns a vector of similarity values of `u1` with all columns in `df2` at the same time.